# When I "Save site as template" in SP 2013, where does it save the file?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've created several templates on my main dev server using "Site Actions" > "Save site as template".    I want to physically move these files to different servers, other dev and QA servers, but they're not where I expected to find them (`%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`).

Can anybody tell me just where these files are supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all placed under special library called `Solution Gallery`. You can find this library by going to the root site, then Site Settings -> Solutions.

Comment: I see the templates there, but I need to actually copy them to other servers on completely different networks.  I don't see anyway to do that from the Solutions Gallery, so I assume I need to get to the actual *.wsp files themselves.

Comment: @s31064: under solution gallery, just hover over solution name and click it. Your browser will start downloading .wsp file. Later you can copy those downloaded .wsp in any other locations.

Comment: That was just way too simple, a true "Duh" moment.  Thanks to you and Eric for your help.

Answer (score 5):

They are stored in the site collections template gallery.

It would be found in `/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

Comment: Opening http://sp.com/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx just opens the Solutions Gallery.  I want to take the physical *.wsp files, copy them to a USB drive, and upload them to a server on another network.  If I can do that from the Solutions Gallery I don't know how and would appreciate any info along those lines, but I suspect I need to get to the actual files themselves.  I tried opening the Solutions Gallery in Windows Explorer, but it said "This folder is empty.", even though the templates show up in the Solutions Gallery.

Comment: ditto what Kai said, my answer and his take you to the same place.